# htaccess redirect to one URL to an URL with Dynamic parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect some urls to some other urls with their parameter, I am doing this with this rule but its not working, am I doing something wrong?

I have URLs like `www.example.com/ranges/some-of-the-range` and I would like to redirect all these to `www.example.com/info/ranges/some-of-the-range`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(ranges/.+)$ /info/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
# non www to www Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# Blog URL Issue
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please also suggest to learn .htaccess in more professional way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot match Request URI in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`. That is used to match domain name only for a web request.

You can have your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(ranges/.+)$ /info/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, Anubhava, its not working and I have updated the question for better understanding :(

Comment: My rule works on my Apache and redirects `/ranges/some-of-the-range` to `/info/ranges/some-of-the-range`. Make sure this is very first rule in your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Yes your htaccess looks fine now and this redirect rule is at right place.